# KeyDown Event to next row

Tags: vb.net, gridview, keydown

I created this form in VS

[image]

The `NumPlace TextBox` is intalized to `1` automatically, I want when I press on the `Enter` key to increment the `NumPlace` automatically in the next row.

This is the code I wrote :

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            MsgBox("Enter key is pressed !")
        End If
    End Sub
```

But It doesn't work it only works when I'm selecting some row end press on "Enter" but when I change the value of the ComboBox or when I select the `NumPlace TextBox` and then I press on `Enter` the event doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried what i suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the event `KeyUp` instead of `KeyDown`

Answer (score 1):

You need to check ColIndex and RowIndex......................

```
Dim currCell As DataGridViewCell = DataGridView1.CurrentCell
```

Comment: by checking the row and column you can avoid the event "DataGridView1_KeyDown" for Combobox and others.

Answer (score 0):

The `DataGridView1_KeyDown` event will only fire when the focus is on `DataGridView1`. try handling `Form1_KeyDown` Event instead.

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            MsgBox("Enter key is pressed !")
        End If
    End Sub
```

However, you should set Form1 `KeyPreview` property to `True` in the `Form Designer` or in `Form Load` so that the form receives key events before the event is passed to the control that has focus.

see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx) for more info

Comment: this event it only fires when I select the form or the DGV when I write something in the textbox and then I press the key Enter the event doesn't fire